# C# to use static class to create collection of the class or to use collection class

Tags: c#, class, collections, static

I have a design problem,

Basically, I have a class called `Currency`

```
public class Currency
{ 
     public int ID;
     public string Name;
     public int RoundingValue;

     public Currency() { }

     public void GetData() { // Some SQL query code // }
}
```

Sometimes it is necessary to fetch all the currencies that there are in the system to make a decision concering exchange rates, compatability of payment, etc.

I see two ways of doing that (fetching data):

1) To make a static method inside `Currency` class to do it. That involves creating SQL connection instance inside it(not sure if that is the right thing to do), creating `List<Currency>` instance to store the collection, and then pass it outside the class.

2) Create collection of the class via extending `Collections.BaseCollection` class, make instance of it, doing the same SQL query, and then return the result. But that class will provide no additional functionality, and probably won't ever (the same for `Currency` itself.

In other cases, I used extended collections, because they needed to store additional info, based on the contents of the collection.

But in this case, no additional info is created or functionality provided.

So, what design would be more practical?
If there is an alternative to the these solutions, I would be more than happy to hear it.

Comment: Have you considered using a [factory design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx).
I don't think the type of currency changes much, only the amount it represents. This way you could do Currency.GetEuro() and/or Currency.GetUSD() and so forth.

Comment: @MarvinBrouwer the reason for not using factory pattern is, that it is unknown beforehand what currencies exist in the system.

Comment: @gcores database specifics, in which data is mainly controlled through 3rd party SPs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply populating a `List<Currency>` then returning it as `IList<Currency>`. That way if you change it in future to use a custom collection, you won't break any consumers.

Comment: can`t seem to follow. Can you please elaborate?